# Pass a selected row details on Datagrid row select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Am unable to get selected row details, instead i am getting all values.

```
   <DataGrid
        justifyContent="end"
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={pageSize}
        onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20]}
        disableSelectionOnClick={true}
        onRowClick={onRowSelect(rows)}
      />

const onRowSelect = (event) => {
  console.log("on row click", event);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function to `onRowClick`, instead you are invoking it with all values.

```
onRowClick={onRowSelect}
```

Read more about row data in [Mui Docs](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/)

Comment: still i am getting all data, instead of the selected

Comment: Do `onRowClick={onRowSelect}`  and check the value

Comment: Working, thanks